# Update a field multiplying another field and a constant in sql with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have to do this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET value1 = (value2 * X)
```

Where value1 and value2 are fields of that table, and X is a constant, defined by the user.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it using PDO syntax for prepared statements.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE mytable SET value1 = value2 * :x");
$stmt->bindParam(':x', $variable_from_user);
$stmt->execute();
```

Mysqli syntax is similar.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE mytable SET value1 = valu2 * ?");
Stmt->bind_param("i", $variable_from_user);
$stmt->execute();
```